# How to prevent re initializaton of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am designing a system. It has a dashboard where my form data is posted and once it is posted there, an automated email using amazon ses is sent. I want to prevent a user from posting their data more than once to my dashboard. That's why I want to add a validation for the above task. I was thinking about an array where I can store the emails, if the email exists axios won't post the data to the dashboard, if the email isn't there, it will be added to the array and the data will be posted but everytime a new form data is posted, the array is re-initialised. I want a solution to this problem.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {
  const [candidate, setCandidate] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    phoneNumber: 0,
    email: "",
    gitProfile: "",
    linkToResume: "",
    designation: "",
    interest: "",
  });

  let emails = [];

  const onChange = e =>
    setCandidate({ ...candidate, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (emails.includes(candidate.email) === false) {
      emails.push = candidate.email;
      axios
        .post("https://webhook.site/f5698dc8-5eec-42db-860b-52ce8f7a347d", {
          candidate,
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res, candidate);
          if (res.status === 200) {
            axios
              .post("http://localhost:5000/", { candidate })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      alert("User Exists");
    }
  };

return(
    //form input data 
  );
}
```

Here whenever I am submitting new data the array `emails[]` is always re initialising and defeating the purpose. Please recommend a fix to this problem.

Comment: The functionality you want here is `useRef`. It lets you store mutable values that don't get reset every render: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref  this obviously won't preserve them if they do something like refresh the page, but that's a separate matter

Comment: how to preserve for page refresh?

Comment: you need to save the emails array to local/session storage. Then, in the initial value of the `useRef`, check if it's in storage and use that, otherwise just use an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Use `React.useRef` hook to create a ref object and push email onto that object.

The refs created from `useRef` persists across re-renders and state changes.

You could read more about `useRef` here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const emails = React.useRef([]);

  const onChange = e =>
    setCandidate({ ...candidate, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!emails.current.includes(candidate.email)) {
      emails.current.push(candidate.email);
      
      // your API call here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this answer worked for me. I know this won't work on server restart but is there anyway that this works on page refresh.

Comment: Nope. You have to store it in `localStorage`. But then again, what happens when the same user enters email from another device? Then, you have to store in the email in your backend. Depending on your use-case, you can store your email in localStorage or server.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by moving

```
let emails = [];
```

outside the component.

Comment: this also works but once the page is refreshed the array is reinitialised.

Comment: In that case it'll always re-initialise even if you use `state` for it.

Comment: If you wants the value of emails variable  to stay even after refresh then you should go for localStorage.